# Match string with optional char

Tags: regex, option-type

I'd like to capture 'com.ouest.france' from the URL below I have attempted to do it using this regex

```
play.google.com\/store\/apps\/details\?id=(.*)[?&]
```

See it here http://www.rubular.com/r/NMxRo4grSL

`https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ouest.france&hl=de
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ouest.france`

However, it does not work if ampersand sign is not present.

Any idea ?

Comment: Is it Ruby you are using?

Comment: Actually Java, but it should be pretty similar

Comment: you can try `play.google.com\/store\/apps\/details\?id=([^&]*).*`

Comment: I think you need to use `URL` from `java.net.*` to parse a URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best to tell to the group to match everything except **&**

```
play.google.com\/store\/apps\/details\?id=([^&]*)
```

http://www.rubular.com/r/JA0rjpQcG9

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your regex expects an `?` or `&` at the end. Make it optional like

```
play.google.com\/store\/apps\/details\?id=(.*?)([?&]|$)
```

which allows the `?`, `&` **or** an end of line.

Regards

Comment: But why would another `?` come in the middle of the query string?

Comment: @torazaburo That `?` is quoted and matches the `?` in the URL.